# How do I construct a timer for a reactive API?

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, reactive-programming

In my Java 9 Spring Boot 2 application, I'm converting uses of synchronous `RestTemplate` calls to asynchronous `WebClient` calls. The synchronous calls are timed with `HdrHistogram` like so:

```
long sentAt = System.nanoTime();

try {
    ResponseEntity<Resource<Order>> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        url, 
        HttpMethod.POST, 
        request, 
        ORDER_PARAMETERIZED_TYPE
        );
} finally {
    histogram.recordValue(System.nanoTime() - sentAt);
}
```

Each asynchronous call-site uses `subscribe` so I could move this timing block out of utility code into application code but I really want to avoid that.

I'd like to do something like:

```
long sentAt = System.nanoTime();

return webClient.post()
    .uri("/orders")
    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(order))
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(ORDER_PARAMETERIZED_TYPE)
    .doFinally(r -> histogram.recordValue(System.nanoTime() - sentAt))
    ;
```

but the histogram in the `doOnSuccess` call (which requires the `sentAt` value) is not recording any values.

So, what's the "Right Way" to do this type of timer interception for reactive APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**

```
long sentAt = System.nanoTime();

return webClient.post()
    .uri("/orders")
    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(order))
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(ORDER_PARAMETERIZED_TYPE)
    .doFinally(r -> histogram.recordValue(System.nanoTime() - sentAt))
    ;
```

**Details**

Actually, it works as written in the question, but it takes a few milliseconds for the data to appear in the `HdrHistogram`. Sadly, this took me a couple of hours to discover...hopefully you'll fare better.